# problema con fpdf al generar documento pdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

tengo un ejemplo sencillo que me baje de una pagina para generar pdf con fpdf y adaptarlo a lo que necesito pero no  me genera el pdf,  baje  otro mas o nada que lo genera, estoy usando php8 en mi servidor, por aca les dejo el código, la entrar en la pagina queda en blanco, le coloque la D en la salida a ver si descargaba el documento o I para  que se abriera y nada

```
echo "aaaaaaaa";
// include class
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');


echo "mmmmm";
// create document
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

// config document
$pdf->SetTitle('Generar archivos PDF con PHP');
$pdf->SetAuthor('Kodetop');
$pdf->SetCreator('FPDF Maker');

// add title
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 24);
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'Generar archivos PDF con PHP', 0, 1);
$pdf->Ln();

// add text
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 7, utf8_decode('Los archivos PDF se utilizan ampliamente en documentos y reportes que necesitan mantener el diseño y contenido (imágenes, tipos de letra, colores, etc), por ello vamos a aprender a crear archivos PDF utilizando PHP.'), 0, 1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 7, utf8_decode('FPDF es una clase PHP que permite la generación de archivos PDF de forma sencilla y sin necesidad de instalar librerías adicionales, cuenta con métodos bien documentados que facilitan su uso.'), 0, 1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 7, utf8_decode('Antes de comenzar lo primero es descargar FPDF e incluir los archivos necesarios en nuestro proyecto.'), 0, 1);
$pdf->Ln();

// output file
$pdf->Output('', 'fpdf-complete.pdf');
echo "bbb";
```

Comment: Algo en el log de PHP?

Comment: Lamento comentarte que el codigo que has compartido se ejecuta correctamente; y muestra el archivo PDF; puedes indicar que URL estas usando para entrar al script??

Comment: Cuando dices `para que se abriera y nada` ¿que es nada?  Es decir, ¿que ocurre **exactamente** cuando ejecutas ese script?  ¿página en blanco? ¿algun error visible? ¿no carga la página? ¿que aparece en la consola del navegador?  **nada** pueden ser muchas cosas :-)

Comment: tambien puedes poner un phpinfo() en el archivo php que estas usando para ver que tienes en el entorno ... que pueda estar molestando el correcto funcionamiento del servidor.

Comment: ok, lo tengo subido en https://dinervent.com/reme/prueba.php  fíjate que edite el código colocándole tres echo  a ver que sale, y ps  si entras a la pagina me sale aaaaaa y mmmmm pero ni el archivo pdf ni al final que le coloque bbb y te coloque el php info tambien a ver

Comment: Pregunta autocontenida. Si matas el sitio, lo cambian o quitan la funcionalidad, los que tengan esta pregunta en el futuro no van a encontrar nada que les sirva.

Comment: Se supone que el archivo fpdf.php esta en la carpeta `...public_html/reme/fpdf/` ¿cierto?

Comment: El archivo fpdf.php esta en ela carpeta fpdf y dentro el archivo, en el mismo directorio donde esta el prueba.php que es a donde estan ingresando  fpdf/fpdf.php

Comment: vale vale, era por si acaso... segun tu **phpinfo** tu archivo _prueba.php_ está en la carpeta `public_html/reme/prueba.php`, por lo tanto el archivo **fpdf.php** debe estar aquí: `public_html/reme/fpdf/fpdf.php` para que lo encuentre.

Comment: Si tal cual esas son las rutas

Comment: en local si se ejecuta, no se me ejecutaba en local por los echo

Comment: Acabo de reproducir el código de tu pregunta en mi ordenador y tambien me pasaba como a ti, y solo veia el `aaaaammmm` pero si lo ejecutaba desde terminal veia tambien caracteres del PDF.  En la consola del navegador he visto un error 500 a pesar que me mostraba ese texto y en el log de errores me dice que `FPDF error: Some data has already been output`,  por lo tanto he quitado los **echo** y ya me funciona bien.

Comment: te juro que antes de la pregunta no tenia los echo  y ahora si ejecuta que le quite los echo :/ pensaran que estoy loco _( pero gracias a todos.

Comment: jeje :-)  Me alegro que ya lo hayas solucionado. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Me paso que cuando lo corria en windows funcionaba pero a la hora de subirlo a produccion en distro de linux debian 11 no funcionaba ese modulo en especifico, debia de lanzarme un alert en la vista que menciona que ha sido creado, pero eso no pasaba y solo generaba una vista en blanco como la que muestras, ahora quiero hacer enfasis en esta parte en especifico ya que se le esta diciendo a la clase que haga un archivo temporal con output el cual crea un archivo temporal en el server que sera pasado a travez de la url entonces quiere decir que si no se imprime es porque ni siquiera lo esta creando para darle salida de modo que me puse a ver los permisos en windows y tenia totalidad de permisos el que importa mas es que tenga el de ejecucion ya que va a comportarse como un script que genera mas archivos de modo que si este archivo no tiene los permisos dados en tu server no va a poder generar este archivo temporal que incluso pude ver que se genera en tiempo de ejecucion en SO windows mas no en linux y ahi empece a indagar a lo que me llevo a ceder permisos al grupo de usuarios y apache para que pueda generarse

$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'Letter');

$pdf -> Output($nombreArchivo, 'F', true);

ahora bien si es error de programacion pueden ir debuggeando con var_dump o echo seguido de un die(); para que se detenga en ese bloque en especifico y ver que esta trayendo
espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo la idea de `Mr. Fox`, de que al parecer la falla está ocurriendo por el archivo temporal que se crea cuando en `$pdf->Output` se especifica `I (In line)` o `D (Download)`, también a mi me ocurrió.
De tal forma que cuando especifiqué la salida a `File $pdf->Output (F)`, el archivo PDF se crea en el servidor (linux) sin problema.
Espero sea de utilidad.